# PHP: Show time based on user's timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I wonder if there is a way to get the timezone of the user in php and then display a time based on viewer's timezone. I know it can be done in javascript but i want a solution in php. I searched a lot but can't find a way to get this work.

So basically suppose the time is 8:30 GMT+0530. Its in indian timezone i want if a user views this in Ne York then it should be 21:30 .

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: I have already done it using js but wanted to know if it can be achieved in php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you added the users Timezone while registering or you know users Timezone somehow, then you can try this...

```
$users = [
    [
        'username' => 'foo',
        'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles'
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'bar',
        'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
    ]
];

foreach ($users as $user) {
    date_default_timezone_set($user['timezone']);
    echo $user['username'] . ' date and time is ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br />';
}
```

Output

```
foo time is 2013-02-28 18:13:49
bar time is 2013-02-28 21:13:49
```

You can also user Timezone in JavaScrpt [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript). Make an Ajax request and Save in PHP Session or database.

Comment: This is so static and useless, you must get the user's informations and set the timezone by them

Comment: It's static for the purpose of demonstration. Of course you don't write your users into an array.

Answer (score 3):

You must get the user information and set the default timezone

Look [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

And [ip geolocation api](http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php)

Comment: What if their API doesn't have a user's IP in their db? JS will **always** return the user's timezone. PHP cannot. Also, doing it like this is not reliable, due to VPN's like iPredator etc.

Comment: In that case you can try with a generic timezone, like $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']

Comment: Why use a generic timezone when you can use the user's actual timezone, provided by JS?

Comment: And if an user have the js disabled? :P

Comment: Then they probably don't wanna see this kinda crap anyway :p

Answer (score 1):

You can get the users timezone by crossing their IP with many available geolocation databases,  such as [IPInfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com/)

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

you will need to register for a free API key, but they also provide you with a working example(above)