# copy data from one sql table to another having less number of columns and a different column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL table called `books` which has columns `Name, ID, Author, Language, Pages, Genres, and Status`. Now, I want to copy data from this table's `Name, ID, Author, and Status` columns to another table called `log` which has columns `Name, ID, Author, Status and TimeStamp.`.
I'm getting the `TimeStamp` from the PHP code which I want to send through the INSERT statement.

[image: Schema for log]

[image: This is the schema of books table]

Here's the code I've been trying:

```
$queryBook = $_GET['ID'];
$currentDate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$stmt4 = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO log (Name, ID, Author, Status) SELECT (Name, ID, Author, Status), ? FROM books WHERE ID = '$queryBook'");
$stmt4 -> bind_param('s', $currentDate);
$stmt4 -> execute();
```

I tried this code as well:

```
$stmt4 = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO log * SELECT Name, ID, Author, Status FROM books WHERE ID = '$queryBook'");
$stmt4 -> execute();
```

I'm getting this error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean`

Comment: what is that random `, ?` in that query for?

Comment: I want to add the value of ```$currentDate``` so I've used ```?``` to bind the param.

Comment: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and ["How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: do not do: `$stmt4 = $conn -> prepare("INS...`,   this `$conn->prepare("INS...` seems better

Comment: I see no date column. Where are you trying to add the date? `d-m-Y H:i:s` is also not mysql date format.

Comment: I want to add the date to TimeStamp column. SInce the server is giving the time in it;s time zone, I've formatted it to string.

Comment: I see no `TimeStamp` in screenshots, nor column list. Why not set the timezone of the server, or use GMT everywhere and convert on output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few other things and eventually, I've got it working.

Here's the working code:

```
$stmt4 = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO log (Name, ID, Author, Status, TimeStamp) SELECT Name, ID, Author, Status, ? FROM books WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt4 -> bind_param('ss', $currentDate, $queryBook);
$stmt4 -> execute();
```

Comment: Change `timestamp` to a `datetime` and use `$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` this will save you tons of work down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting the datetime *in the table* using a default value.  Hence, you don't need to pass that in.  On the other hand, you should be sending in `$queryBook` as a parameter.  So, I would recommend defining the table log as :

```
create table log (
   . . . 
   timestamp datetime default now()
);
```

Then your code would look something like this:

```
$stmt4 = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO log (Name, ID, Author, Status) SELECT Name, ID, Author, Status FROM books WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt4 -> bind_param('s', $queryBook);
$stmt4 -> execute();
```

Comment: The problem with adding the now() function is, it is giving me the time of the server. I want it to give me the time in my timezone which is IST.

Comment: time is time, so your local time should be the same as the time from the server (taking into account the difference in timezone)

Comment: That's fine @Luuk, but I want it to look the same as my timezone.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, let's say I have a different column and not the datetime column.  How do you suggest I should solve this problem?

Comment: @VishalA.: [PHP: Show time based on user's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149186/php-show-time-based-on-users-timezone)

Comment: @VishalA. . . . You are much, much safer using the server time for the rows in the database.  After all, the application time can vary -- for instance, people can access the application from anywhere in the world. or people might travel, and so on.