# PHP - How to read their browser timezone and display various set local class times in their time?

Tags: php, timezone

I'm learning PHP.

I have online classes on Zoom at 11:00, 15:00, and 19:00 BST which is UT+1, but I need to display on a (WordPress) webpage what times they are in the student's local time.
In other words, set up a web page to query their browser to get their timezone offset and add that to my local class times so they can display in their timezone's times.

Comment: Hi @Skipper, thanks for providing some background on your question. Can you explain what you've tried so far and where you're stuck? The code you have so far would be helpful too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Show time based on user's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149186/php-show-time-based-on-users-timezone)

Comment: If not, you can use javascript to check the time offset, then convert the date and time of your event to whatever timezone the user is using locally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a 3 o'clock Zoom class each day, I want the user to be able to see what time the class is for them if they are in a different timezone and show this to them when they sign up. So for example for someone in London it would be 3 o'clock because that is my timezone too, but if someone looks at my website from say Texas which is GMT minus 6 the class time will appear as 9am.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from PHP. To get the user's local time, use JavaScript instead of PHP.

```
const d = new Date();
let years = Math.round(d.getTime() / year);
```

PHP only gives back the server's time.